# How to check if a URL is accessible from a PC?

Tags: java, struts-1

We are using struts 1.3 in our application. We have a requirement as stated below -

We have button in login page. Now,

1. If a url is accessible from the user PC, show the button.
2. Otherwise don't show it.

To check the URL accessibility, I am using XMLHttpRequest.responseText. Below is my code :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test html page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function checkURL()
      {
        var xmlHttp = null;
        var theUrl = "http://www.googlewetuyyu.co.in";
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
        alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="checkURL();">
    <b>Hello World!</b>
  </body>
</html>
```

But still I am getting nothing in alert box.

[I am modifying a little bit]

It's actually working in IE. But not working in chrome. Please suggest a solution.

Thanks, 
Kartic

Comment: This is not clear, what could block the user to access an URL ? If the network blocks it, or if the browser doesn't support it? You should explain that better.

Comment: @Alexandre: Sorry for it. If network blocks it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since cross domain AJAX requests wont work because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), I suggest 2 ways doing it.

**Include a an override CSS file**

```
<link type="text/css" href="http://website.com/normal.css" />
<link type="text/css" href="http://otherwebsite.com/override.css" />

<div id="login" class="login">
    <!-- Your button code -->
</div>
```

normal.css

```
.login
{
    display: none;
}
```

override.css

```
#login
{
    display: block;
}
```

If the client has access to the `http://otherwebsite.com`, the style will be overriden since the CSS file will be loaded and ID is more important than class.

**Image load test**

```
<img id="img" style="width: 0;height: 0;" src="http://otherdomain.com/smallimage.png" />
<script>
    $("#img").load(function() { alert("image loaded correctly"); })
    .error(function() { alert("error loading image"); });
</script>
```

Comment: @Kartic Thank you for the comment, I've just tested, and adding a timeout resolve it, now I'm passing the status so you can compare yourself != 404, also a timeout callback could be usefull but not necessary :)

Comment: @Kartic in Chrome, the Available will return 0 so you can use it. In FireFox, you will get Timeout AND Available 0, in IE8 you will get Timeout only. In all cases you can achieve what you want.

Comment: In IE I am getting correct status (0/200). But in Mozilla and Chrome, I am always getting status as 0.

Comment: @Kartic Updated since it was impossible the way I was thinking.

Comment: Second solution (Image load test) looks great. I'll give a try in actual environment and let you know. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Alexandre, Now in second approch, I have another issue. If the URL mentioned in src attribute is blocked, in that case also this code is showing alert "Client has access to otherdomain.com". Can you please suggest any solution.

Comment: @Kartic When you say that user is blocked, will he be able to load the image with `http://domain/path-to-image.png` ? I've tested this solution with Internet Explorer 8, Firefox 22 and Chrome 27 without issue.

Comment: Alexandre, No, he won't. Lets say, "http://domain/" is blocked by proxy. So, http://domain/path-to-image.png won't be loaded. In that case also, I am getting "Client has access to otherdomain.com". I really appreciate your help. Thank you so much.

Comment: Alexandre, I have tried your code, but unfortunately but it dosen't work. The execution stops at line "$("#img").load(function() { alert("image loaded correctly"); })". Please help.

Comment: Sorry! my fault. I'll give a try that you have posted and let you know.

Comment: Alexandre, It solved my issue. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

Use [HttpUrlConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) class. It's getResponseCode() if returns value of 2XX means that the url is working fine from your PC.

You can also use [HttpComponents-HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/index.html) from apache.
Here's a short snippet of doing that,

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("url_to_check");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
```

You can also attach a responseHandler to the execute object to simplify things.

Comment: Am afraid this is incorrect. All HTTP codes in 200 sequence are mostly fine. Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: Hi Arham, Thanks for your help. I have to check whether the URL is accessible from the pc, from where I am opening the login page. Can I do that using HttpConnection? Can you please post a piece of code?

Comment: @Chris That's all right, `getResponseCode()` will return -1 if no code can be discerned from the response or throw an IOException if no connection can be made. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getResponseCode%28%29)

Comment: @Kartic I've updated my answer. You can use HttpClient from Apache. Apache also provides HttpCore which is a low level API to perform such tasks.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are running an applet in the client side**:

You could send a HTTP request using `URLConnection` class as follows:

```
String url = "http://www.mywebsite.com";
String query = "param1=value1";
URLConnection connection = new URL(url + "?" + query).openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
```

If your are being a proxy, you could specify using:

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=webcache.example.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
```

If you want to send a HTTPS request, you cound use [HttpsURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html).

**If you have HTML being rendered in the browser, use Javascript**:

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = null;

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

Comment: That's a Java code, can you suggest how to execute that on the user PC, and enable/disable the button on the page.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help! I have to check whether the URL is accessible from the pc, from where I am opening the login page. Can I do that using HttpConnection or URLConnection? Can you please post a piece of code?

Comment: @Kartic `URLConnection` is from JDK and `HTTPConnection` is from apache commons. I would recommend going to thirdparty libraries only when you cannot achieve it using JDK

Comment: @Chris - Yes true. I will try your code and let you know if it works for me.

Comment: Hi Chris,

I have tried your code. But I am getting nothing as response string. I have posted my code as well. Please help.

Thanks,
Kartic